# Pass data from method to method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, nsarray

```
- (void) getArrray : (NSArray*)arrray{
NSLog(@"Get Array %@",arrray);
}

-(DraggableView *)createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
      draggableView.information.text = [exampleCardLabels objectAtIndex:index]
}
```

I want the arrray data to examplecardlabels with out disturbing the methods. How could I get the data to createdraggable method from getdata method

please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

Make either a `property` or a `global variable` in this class, then set it in the one method and read the value in the other method.

```
@implementation myClass 
{
   NSArray* myArrayData;
}

- (void) getArrray : (NSArray*)arrray{
   NSLog(@"Get Array %@",arrray);
   myArrayData = array;
}

-(DraggableView *)createDraggableViewWithDataAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
   draggableView.information.text = [myArrayData objectAtIndex:index];
}
}
```

Comment: I tried in a way but i m confused. can u solve . give me a sample

Comment: added more detail, hope it helps?

Comment: if u want more help, i need more information.. did you change all 3 places?

Comment: I imported tinder cards classess  from https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards to swift please download this and pass the data from view controller to dragabbleviewbackground class.

Comment: var draggableBackground : DraggableViewBackground = DraggableViewBackground()
        draggableBackground.frame = self.view.frame
        draggableBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.addSubview(draggableBackground)
        
        var brdarray: NSMutableArray = ["A","B","C"]
        draggableBackground.initWithInitialArray(brdarray)
I am sending like this from view contoller

Comment: DragabbleViewBackground class      -(void)initWithInitialArray: (NSMutableArray *)myArray;
{
    myData = myArray;
    NSLog(@"My Data %@",myData);
}  like this the data is coming when showing in a UI the array is empty

Comment: if not understand ask me again i will explain u in a bettter way

Comment: draggableView.information.text = [myData objectAtIndex:index]; to show like this